# Identifier 'PIPELINED' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

My Code is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_ptf (p_rows IN NUMBER) 
RETURN PIPELINED AS 
BEGIN FOR i IN 1 .. p_rows 
LOOP 
PIPE ROW('Value is '||i);
END LOOP;
RETURN; 
END;
```

Error I get is

> : PLS-00201: identifier 'PIPELINED' must be declared

what can be the solution?

Comment: The Oracle documentation is online, comprehensive and free. It comes with lots of examples which will make it easy for you to diagnose your own syntax errors. For instance [here is the section on creating pipelined functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#GUID-58D850B2-A416-47EA-8803-8936E2D6748A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first define a collection type for the elements that you are planning to return from your function. Since it's a string that you're returning, a `table of VARCHAR2` should be your preferred option.

```
create or replace type numval_type as table of VARCHAR2(30);
```

Now, mention this return type before the `PIPELINED` keyword.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_ptf (p_rows IN NUMBER) 
RETURN  numval_type PIPELINED AS  -- type should be specified here after return
BEGIN FOR i IN 1 .. p_rows 
LOOP 
  PIPE ROW('Value is '||i);
 END LOOP;
RETURN; 
END;
/
```

Call it as

```
select * from TABLE(get_tab_ptf(100));
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7a9e779828e512ffca521e5e8a292458)